# Android: How to close one activity on backpress and the entire backstack on another button press?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, onbackpressed

I have this scenario where I have a Main Activity and an Article Activity. The Main Activity opens an Article Activity, then if you click on a related article from the Article Activity, it opens the same activity again with the requested related article. So basically you can open 10 Article Activities on the top of each other and go back through every single one of them onBackPress() until you reach the Main Activity again. But the client also want a button that should send you directly back to the Main Activity without having to cycle through the entire BackStack again.

- Basically we have MA -> AA ->  AA ->  AA -> (...).
- On Back Press you should go back like MA <- AA <-  AA <- AA sequentially through every new instance.
- On Close All button press you should close all AA instances and go back straight to MA.

P.S. I don't want to lose the instance of MA. It should always be there in the backstack as the starting point.

How do I do this?

Comment: Just close AA activity when you open next AA activity which means you have only MA->AA only

Comment: @Shane No, that is precisely what the client doesn't want. He wants to be able to go pack through each and every one of the AA activities .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can make a start function for your main activity and add required flags to Intent for clearing back stack and call that function in onClick of your button. also to avoid having multiple instances of MainActivity you should make its lunch mode *singleInstance* or *singleTop* in your manifest.for the start function you have multiple ways to implement.

**first way**: define a static method in your MainActivity like this
addFlags part is to clear the back stack when you call MainActivity if it's not necessary you can remove it

```
companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun startActivity(context: Context) {
            val intent = Intent(context, KYCActivity::class.java).apply {
                addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or 
                     Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
            }
            context.startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
```

and you can call it in your button click listener

```
gotoHomeButton.setOnClickListener {
    MainActivity.startActivity(context)
}
```

**second way**: define a extention function for starting activities

```
inline fun <reified T: Activity> Context.startActivity() {
    startActivity(Intent(this, T::class.java).apply {
        addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or 
             Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
    })
}
```

and then call the function like this

```
gotoHomeButton.setOnClickListener {
    startActivity<MainActivity>()
}
```

it's not necessary to define these functions, you can just make a new instance of Intent in your buttons onClick but I like it this way.

**UPDATE FROM OP**

It apparently was as easy as adding (Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) flags to the AA activity on the Intent in button click. No need to add anything in manifest.

Comment: But isn't this a memory leak? Because you are basically starting MainActivity again on goHomeButton press? If you do that 10 times, won't you start 10 MainActivities on the top of eachother? Or that's exactly what those flags will prevent?

Comment: no, because you make MainActivity lunch mode singleInstance(in your manifest as I mentioned before) there will be always only one Instance of your activity

Comment: I will try this and give some feedback

Comment: android:launchMode="singleInstance"

Answer (score 0):

You should call intent with `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP` flag to remove all other activities in the stack